# Get selected value from Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to get the value selected by the Customer from the contact form and change the role but it does not work.
For example: If the customer choose product type with Kitchen Appliances. It will change the role of the customer.
Here are the select from contact form:

```
Product Type: [select* ProductType "Home Appliances" "Kitchen Appliances" "Baby & Mummy Products" "Medical Equipments" "Gadget / Others"]
```

Here are my function:

```
function changerole_wpcf7( $contact_form ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            $user_id = $user->ID;
            $user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);
            $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;      
            $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

            if ( $cf7->id() == 1122 ) {
              if($submission && $cf7->ProductType == 'Kitchen Appliances') {
                if ( in_array( 'subscriber', $user_roles ) ) {
                    wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'royal' ) );

                }
            }
        } else { return; }  
    }
}

add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'changerole_wpcf7' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by getting the value through $_POST

```
if ( $cf7->id() == 1122 ) {
   if($submission) {
      $prodType = $_POST['ProductType'];                  
      if($prodType == 'Kitchen Appliances'){
         wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'role' => 'royal' ) );
      }
   }
}
```

Besides, using wpcf7_before_send_mail will help to hook.